# How can I send a layout or webview content to another activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview

I have 2 activities in my project. In my first activity, I have button and a layout name is `m_MyWebView`. In my layout folder I have webviewlayout and I can set that in my `m_MyWebView` layout at my code. I want that, after I've clicked the button, the other activity will have been opened (it is not problem) and another `WebView` I have in my 'compose' layout will have got the content like webviewlayout's. But how can do that with intents, I don't know. Because I cannot send a content with intent.

Here is my code:

my ForwardReplyActivity class:

```
public class ForwardReplyActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageButton m_Reply;
    private WebView webview;
    private LinearLayout m_MyWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        m_MyWebView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyWebViewL);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.webviewlayout,
                m_MyWebView, false);
        WebView wb = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.WebViewim);

        //wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                "bla bla bla", "text/html", "UTF-8",
                null);

        m_MyWebView.addView(view);
        m_Reply = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        m_Reply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ForwardReplyActivity.this,
                        Compose.class);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

and my Compose class:

```
public class Compose extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.compose);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What i have understood from your question is, that you want to use some data from one activity to another,

so then you need to `putExtras` with your intent.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i know putExtras will be used, however i cannot use it with webview's content..

Comment: what sort of content you need, the state of webview? mention it, this would help in understanding your question.